# How are standard libraries, tools and app server platforms typically selected in large organizations?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, standards

I'm looking for a list of criteria for selecting **standard** development libraries, tools, and application servers (specifically Java EE) that is common across large organizations. If your experience doesn't span across multiple large orgs, answering with how this is conducted within your current org is still helpful. Also - 'standard' doesn't mean mandatory or exclusive, only that alternatives must be technically justified.

1. Who selects or recommends dev tools? Does it come from a low, mid, or high level? (actual developers/subject matter experts, project managers, middle management, upper management, a Gartner/Forrester/etc, ?)
2. Who or what is the final say in resolving the inevitable **disputes** in selecting a standard? (Ex. say you have X developers or Y group representatives who cannot agree on some standard tool, library, etc) Is there a committee which votes, a management authority figure (at what level?), some set of subject matter experts, etc?

Extra points:

**Are** there standard development libraries, tools, and app server software within your organization at all? If so how well are they adhered to? Are there "de facto standards"? Is there no standard or a decentralized way of doing business? Are there primary/secondary or "recommended" standards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen as many cases as large companies I have worked in. In some places, there is a strictly standardized technology stack, while in others tools and platforms are selected ad hoc by each dev team and project. And of course anything is possible between these two extremes. I don't think there is any "typical" case.

My current employer has small developer teams in several countries, who have been working separately from each other up to now - so much so that some projects have been duplicated over several countries with close to the same business goals and content. We have just started the first steps toward standardization and selecting common dev tools. The solutions will be built pragmatically, based on the current choices, unifying gradually over a longer period of time.

In another place several years ago, we had a strictly standardized dev environment and an extensive proprietary GUI framework to build everything upon. All has been decided and designed in advance, top-down. Even for refactoring ideas, we had to get permission from the boss of the boss of our boss - who then in the end said "no" :-/

Comment: No "typical" case is good in a way (more flexibility). I'm thinking level of centralization should hinge on how closely development groups work together.

Comment: IMO often a major driver for standards is addressing long term O&M challenges. If you're supporting a dozen different technologies it's *probably* going to be harder than supporting two or three, if we can assume those few do the job reasonably well in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

Large organizations that I've dealt with are always dynamic ecosystems that are evolving all the time.  They tend to oscillate between "dispersion is better" and "centralization is better" with a period that is somewhere between 1-5 years.

If the organization is on its "centralization is better" cycle, there's an enterprise architecture group that will claim tool selection and standardization as their responsibility.  They'll have a committee of wise men/women that dictate selections from on high.  They're usually conservative, as all large organizations tend to be.  They like mainstream, proven technologies that are produced by other large organizations that have deep enough pockets to be sued if anything goes wrong.

This enterprise architecture group will usually have the final say.  They own the production servers, and nothing unapproved can appear on production servers.

But there's always a guerrilla war going on in the lines of business.  Depending on their appetite for innovation and risk, each group can be searching for unapproved technologies to give them an edge.  They'll prototype things to see if they can persuade the enterprise group to allow them to continue.

This continues until the "dispersion cycle" begins and someone, usually a new incoming CIO, decides to break with the past and try "new ideas".

And the circle of life continues.

Comment: I'm not sure about the oscillation, but I've seen the "large bloated organizations and huge kitchen-sink tools are safest" flavor-aid as popular. The way I look at it, that's a reactive strategy (upon failure, assign blame and take legal action), but I prefer a proactive strategy to prevent the failure in the first place.

Comment: Better find smaller organizations.

Comment: @duffymo There has to be some way to find a middle ground!

Comment: Why does there have to be?  Can you see that large organizations tend to be conservative, freighted with history, and risk averse?  That individuals will have less influence as the number of people to be won over increases?  That's why people who don't like that kind of thing jump to smaller organizations, where they can "make a difference".  Then they take on another set of problems, like generating revenue and making payroll every two weeks.  There aren't many nirvanas.

Comment: That's just a pessimistic view. I just don't think it's such a black and white thing when there is plenty of room for shades of gray. If you can identify what should be centralized and what should be decentralized, and then implement policy that reflects that, it has to be an improvement over maintaining status quo.

Comment: My point is that in large organizations the number of people you have to convince goes up rapidly.  If my view's pessimistic, yours is naive.  At least mine is based on personal experience in both large and small organizations.  What's the basis for yours?  Wishes?  Faith?  Because you say so?  Good luck.

Comment: No need to get defensive. It's obvious that the number of people who need to be swayed in one way or another increases. (Not that it matters if you have your CIO's backing and you're one of the ones setting the standards.) My main point is that there has to be some optimal strategy. It doesn't seem as if many people put a lot of thought into this topic. Large orgs often have *more* luxury to take risks. I have to wonder how much money they're wasting on overpriced junk just because they're too afraid to even evaluate something new.

Comment: Nobody's being defensive, just arguing a point.  Yours is a good one, except for one word: optimal.  Do you think you know what that is?  And don't you agree that it evolves very quickly?  Last year's optimal, browser-based JSP solution might be swept away entirely by the coming of mobile phones.  The rest of your point is correct: a big cash cushion makes big mistakes possible that would kill a smaller firm.

Comment: I realize that expecting to reach an "optimal/perfect" state is going to disappoint, but there's nothing wrong with striving for a goal even if you never reach it. Yeah it changes rapidly, it's dependent on specifics of each individual organization, and it's hard to even agree on what is optimal.  But giving up (working towards a balanced and optimal standardization strategy) almost guarantees inefficiency, right? There should be white papers and books on the subject, IMO, but it's hard to find anything (unless I'm looking in the wrong places).

Comment: (Btw, if there does happen to be actual published work on the subject, PLEASE don't let it be some drooling MBA written gibberish! Heck even CIOs I've known don't understand the topic in the least.)